# Differentiating a trained simple neural net with tensorflow gives the wrong result and changes model weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to teach a neural net a simple function (`f(t) = 2t`) and then compute derivative with respect to input (`df/dt = 2`). I use a net with one dense layer and no activation:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, input_shape=(1,), bias_initializer='ones'))
opt = RMSprop(lr=0.01, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])#optimizer=opt,
model.summary()
```

My data consist of pairs `t -> f(t)`, where `t` is chosen randomly on `[0, 1]` to compute `df/dt` of my net I found this code:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/keras-users/g2JmncAIT9w/36MJZI7NBQAJ
and https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l9YdIa2N40Fj3Y09qb3r3RhqKPXoaVJC

This is my full code on colab:

```
model.fit(train_x ,train_y, epochs=100,validation_data=(test_x, test_y),shuffle=False, batch_size=32)
model.layers[0].get_weights()# this displays 2.0069, quite right
outputTensor = model.output
listOfVariableTensors = model.inputs[0]
gradients = k.gradients(outputTensor, listOfVariableTensors)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
evaluated_gradients = sess.run(gradients,feed_dict={model.input:np.array([[10]])})
evaluated_gradients # this displays kinda random number
model.layers[0].get_weights() # this displays same number as above
```

I believe my model performs a simple `w*t + b` transform, so its derivative should be just `w`. But the code I found provides wrong results and breaks trained weights. I actually think it resets them to initial weights because if I initialize dense layer weights with `kernel_initializer= "ones"`, the code returns 1 as a derivative.

So, I need help with correct derivation of neural net.

Comment: `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())` initializes all variables...

Answer (score 0):

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession() # run this before anything happens
#....   
model.fit(train_x ,train_y, epochs=100,validation_data=(test_x, test_y),shuffle=False, batch_size=32)
model.layers[0].get_weights()# this displays 2.0069, quite right
outputTensor = model.output
listOfVariableTensors = model.inputs[0]
gradients = k.gradients(outputTensor, listOfVariableTensors)        
evaluated_gradients = sess.run(gradients,feed_dict={model.input:np.array([[10]])})
evaluated_gradients
```